# Bootstrap buttons margin-right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im using this html with bootstrap Framework:

```
<div id="postsPerPage">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="5">5</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort active filter" title="10">10</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="25">25</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="50">50</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="100">100</button>
</div>
```

please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/boriskamp1991/vppt8qvm/2/

Why is there a untraceable margin between the buttons? I need this to be 0 beacuse I want to work with percent width units and this messes it up.....

I have really no clue after searching and searching.
You can find the margin on their doc page as well: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "margin" is due to the whitespace between the `<button>` elements. If you really *do* want the look of five individual buttons, and not of a button group, as suggested in the answer by Tim Lewis, you can remove the whitespace:

```
<div id="postsPerPage">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="5">5</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort active filter" title="10">10</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="25">25</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="50">50</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="100">100</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! you're a hero! is it default behaviour for buttons to automatically add whitespace when each button is placed on it's own line of code instead of entered all on the same line?

Comment: I'm happy to help.
The buttons are inline-block elements, and as such, the spaces (and in this case, newlines) between them are rendered just like the spaces between words in a sentence. [This page](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) details a number of ways to "fight" the spaces.

Comment: Thanks for checking back and explaining Jacob! It all makes sense now

Answer (score 4):

Add a `<div class="btn-group">` around your... **button group**:

```
<div id="postsPerPage">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="5">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort active filter" title="10">10</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="25">25</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="50">50</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="100">100</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

That will get rid of the spacing between them.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vppt8qvm/4/)

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the `btn-group` class. Because of responsiveness reasons I don't want the `btn-group`, I want full control over my buttons to make them stack next to eachother on large format and span 50% width on smaller screens etc. This can be perfectly achieved if the white space between the buttons was 0.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Tim Lewis's answer, you can optionally just add the btn-group class to the same div that has id="postsPerPage". Looking something like this:

```
<div id="postsPerPage" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="5">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort active filter" title="10">10</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="25">25</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="50">50</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sort filter" title="100">100</button>
</div>
```